# Can you dereference a shared_ptr in a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Im trying to pass a shared_ptr into a templated function and dereference it inside that function. Ex:

```
constexpr bool test(std::shared_ptr<Type>&val) const
{
   return val->some_bool;
}
```

Besides dereferencing it before passing in is there a way to dereference smart pointers inside a constexpr?

Comment: As far as I know only the default constructor and `nullptr` constructor are `constexpr` so I don't see how you would get a dereferenceable `shared_ptr` in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: It is not recommended to pass `shared_ptr` as an argument unless your function needs to share ownership. The latter certainly does not make sense for `constexpr` function,

Comment: Agreeing with the first comment: You seem to be skipping an important step here. Why do you have doubts about dereferencing, but haven't had any doubts about whether or not you can create a (non-empty) `std::shared_ptr` that may be dereferenced at compile-time in the first place? Or why do you have `constexpr` on that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function you want inside a constexpr function. However, that doesn't mean that the constexpr function can actually be evaluated at compile-time. At compile time, only constexpr functions can be called, so if a constexpr function calls a non-constexpr function, then the former cannot be evaluated at compile time.

The `operator*` and `operator->` functions, and `operator[]` in the case of an array, which you would use to deference a `shared_ptr`, are not `constexpr` and therefore cannot be called at compile time. And, as pointed out in the comments, there is no constructor for `shared_ptr` that would even allow you to create a non-null `constexpr` `shared_ptr` in the first place, or to create a non-null `shared_ptr` at compile time.